# Extracting excel content from client side Web Application

Tags: javascript, excel, actionscript-3, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I have a web application (ASP.Net) that needs to upload a file

I've been looking for a framework to extract data from excel on the client side and submit the content (JSON, CSV) format into the server side to lessen the traffic. I've looked into ActiveXObject in javascript but it only works in internet explorer. I have an option to use silverlight or actionscript to do the parsing.

Question:

> Is silverlight really dead? can't i use it on the long run?
>
> Is this possible using action script?
>
> Is there any javascript framework to do this kind of parsing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JS-XLSX JavaScript library](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) to parse file on client side and then send the content of parsed spreadsheet to the server.

For example you can create a button (see HTML code below), then call loadBinaryFile() on change event, parse it with JS-XLSX library and send it to the server with $.post() or other similar function.

The structure of workbook is a JSON object and it is well described in documentation at JS-XLSX site.

```html
<script src="http://alasql.org/console/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>    

<input type="file" onchange="parseAndSend(event)" value="Parse and send XSLS file">
  
<script>
    function parseAndSend (event) {
        // Load binary file from desktop
        loadBinaryFile(event,function(data){
            // Parse it to JSON
      var workbook = XLSX.read(data,{type:'binary'});
            // Send to server data from workbook here
            // $.post({url:'http://mypostaddress',data:workbook});
            alert(workbook.SheetNames);
        });
    }

    function loadBinaryFile(path, success) {
            var files = path.target.files;
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var name = files[0].name;
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var data = e.target.result;
                success(data);
            };
            reader.readAsBinaryString(files[0]);
    }
</script>
```